# jQuery making a function

Tags: jquery

I have following js:

```
var rhp_s4_left ='<div class="col s4 rhpop_left">';
var rhp_s7_left ='<div class="col s7 rhpop_left">';
var rhp_s4_right ='<div class="col s4 rhpop_right">';
var rhp_s5_right ='<div class="col s5 rhpop_right">';           
var rhp_s6_right ='<div class="col s6 rhpop_right">';
var rhp_s12_right ='<div class="col s12 rhpop_right">';
var rhp_s4_extra ='<div class="col s4 rhpop_extra">';
```

I want to simplify it by making a function:

```
function RHC(a,b){
    '<div class="col s'+ a +' rhpop_'+ b +'">';
}
```

Then,

```
var rhp_s6_extra ='<div class="col s6 rhpop_extra">';
```

will be

```
var rhp_s6_extra = RHC("6","extra");
```

Of course this is not correct, but I am not sure how to make it work. Can someone show me ? Thanks!

Comment: return your string, and you are done.

Comment: the string in the function should be returned

Comment: Ah,,, that was a silly mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add a return to your function:

```
function RHC(a,b){
    return '<div class="col s'+ a +' rhpop_'+ b +'">';
}

var rhp_s6_extra = RHC("6","extra");
```

In your actual code you are only adding a string into the function body. Returning it will apply the string to the calling variable.

Comment: You forgot to call the function.